# why does a x100 oscilloscope probe grant a wider bandwidth than a x10 probe

Tags: rf, oscilloscope, probe

I was asked in an interview the question                                          "why does A x100 oscilloscope probe grant a wider bandwidth than a x10 probe? How much does it widen it?".

Comment: [This video covers some relevant things.](http://youtu.be/OiAmER1OJh4) I'm not certain (and I haven't watched the video), but I think the difference in capacitance causes the change in bandwidth due to a different rise time.

Comment: That's a dumb question. I have a x10 probe at the desk in front of me which has twice the bandwidth than a x100 probe, also on my desk next to the first one. Under the desk, I have a x1 probe with the bandwidth wider than other two probes combined - it is active though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used a x100 probe, but I'd guess less capacitance.. same thing from x1 to x10.  Bandwidth goes as 1/RC at low frequency,  at some point that has to stop.

Comment: Thank you I figured it out.:)    
BW=0.35/(Risetime)    
Risetime=2.2(Rin*Cprobe)    
for x10 probe :    
Cprobe=15pf    
for x100 probe :    
Cprobe=2pf

Comment: @user4422012, excellent.  I measured the (DC) capacitance of a x1 probe the other day it was about 100 pF.  Do you know it's perfectly alright to answer your own question?  You could add some links to different probes.

Comment: You probably measured the coax cable capacitance